# 2nd account / repo push issue

Tags: git, github

I'm fairly new at this stuff - I have a professional github company account that was first set up for the last few months. Recently, I've been working through some rails tutorials. I created one tutorial repository and pushed under my personal account without any trouble.

However, for some reason after following the steps for a second project I am trying to work on, I get this error message:

```
ERROR: Permission to <username>/<projectname>.git denied to <businessaccount>.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Why is it trying to use my business account for this repo? And how do I make it take my personal account info instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The account info being used by git to authenticate with the remote server can be mentioned as part of the remote's URL.

```
<USERNAME>@<REMOTE_HOSTNAME>:<REMOTE_REPO_URL>
```

If you do not give any username, git starts to use your currently logged in user's username automatically.

Github does not allow using the same set of SSH keys for multiple accounts unfortunately. So you would need to generate another set of SSH keys (i.e. a keypair) for your personal github account.

1. Generate a new ssh keypair for your personal account

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.personal -C "Keypair for Personal Github account"
   ```
2. Add the following lines to your `~/.ssh/config` file to make SSH use the new keypair whenever referring the host by `personal.github.com`:

   ```
   Host personal.github.com
   User git
   HostName github.com
   PreferredAuthentications publickey
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.personal
   ```
3. For every repo you plan to use, using the personal github account, make sure to use the hostname `personal.github.com` in the URL instead of `github.com`. In addition the `git@` username part can be omitted, since we have already mentioned that in the `~/.ssh/config`. So either of these should now work.

   ```
   git clone personal.github.com:keecham/blacktie.git
   git clone git@personal.github.com:keecham/blacktie.git
   ```
4. Your work github account and the keys remain untouched this way, and should not be affected.

Comment: Thanks for responding. It's a public repo that I just created today on GitHub. https://github.com/keecham/blacktie

I have tried generating an SSH key for my personal e-mail, but it says I already have one. When I copy and paste that SSH key to my personal github account, it says it's already in use somewhere. No idea what's going on.

Comment: @KishoreEechambadi - I've updated my answer with instructions on how to use a different SSH keypair for each of the github accounts.

Comment: Thanks! All the steps worked - I created a new pair of ssh keys, (created and) added those lines to the config file, and was able to clone the repo (though it's currently empty). However, when I try to git push it still says permission denied to <businessaccount>. How do I push as the personal user? And how do I toggle between the two?

Comment: @KishoreEechambadi - Can you post the output for `git show origin` ? Especially the info about `Fetch URL` and `Push URL`.

Comment: blacktie keecham$ git show origin
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions

Comment: I got it! I did `git remote show origin`, which showed that the personal subdomain was not being used yet. I then did `git remote set-url' to change it to the personal domain. Just did a git push and it worked perfectly! I'm guessing that in the future, if I want to switch to my work repo, I have to first do the 'git remote set-url' to the regular github.com domain? Thanks a lot for your help, it's much appreciated!

Comment: @KishoreEechambadi - Are you trying to use a single local repo with 2 different remote repos that you want to access using 2 different accounts? If so, you can create 2 different remotes for the same local repo. That way, you do not need to run `remote set-url` to switch URLs, and you can specify the remote you want to pull from or push to.